# PHP script has an error but nothing shows

Tags: php

Hey all I changed the script to read like this now however now when I click on the go button it just shows a blank white screen The html is working as the go button is being pushed:

```
    <?php

   if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "nishantrama@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Sva Sva Spa Salon Coming Soon Notify Email";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if (!isset($_POST['email'])
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.'));       


$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";


   // create email headers
   $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n";
   'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" ;
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
   $mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

 }
 ?>

  !-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you soon to let you know when      
the new website will be up and running.
To go back to the home page click <a href="http://www.svaspasalon.com">Here</a>

 <?php
  ?>

 MY FORM HTML:
  <form name="contactform" method="post" action="contact.php">
            <input  type="text"  name="email" placeholder="Provide    
   EMAIL for Reminder" maxlength="80" size="30">
            <input type="submit" class="go" value="">       
        </form>
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: what about configuring apache to display errors?

Comment: Try `var_dump`ing `$_POST['email']`.  This might be a problem with your HTML form.  (I love randomly making nouns into verbs).

Comment: @ Superscript I have added my form html link here: <form name="contactform" method="post" action="contact.php">
    <input  type="text"  name="email" placeholder="Provide EMAIL for Reminder" maxlength="80" size="30">
        <input type="submit" class="go" value="">  
   </form>

Comment: Please see http://docforge.com/wiki/PHP/Debugging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never define `$mail`, so your final `if()` test is utterly pointless.

```
$mail = mail(...);
^^^^^^^--- need this

if ($mail) { ... } else { ... }
```

General tip: **NEVER** use the `@` error suppression operator, especially when you're having trouble. It's the coding equivalent of sticking your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you lalalalalalal".

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement contains an errant `||` so the `if` is trying to evaluate the call to `died` as true or false (meaning that `died` *always* gets run)

Change:

```
if (!isset($_POST['email']) ||
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.')
) ;
```

To

```
if (!isset($_POST['email'])
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
```

Comment: and it never gets to that part of code unless `$_POST['email']` is set: so there are more errors than this one.

Comment: it wouldn't print anything if `$_POST['email']` is not set since all of the code is wrapped in an if block

Answer (score 0):

Fist: mail function working only smtp server installed machine. May be you skipped it.

Second: you did use @mail. @ symbol passivated mail function error.

Answer (score 0):

To see errors, put this at the top (remove it before putting the code in production!):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```